# How to fix this issues on uploading app to appstore in ios

Tags: ios, swift

I have tried uploading my app to app store but i got the following issues i have provided the details on the screenshot[image: error details] . Anyone knows the problem ? Thank You.

Answer (score 4):

You have add one additional app icon size with 1024px * 1024px in `Assets.xcassets`:
[image]

**Error2:** The "fix" was to make sure that the image `assests` file under the watch extension had all targets unchecked and the assets file under the watch app should only be checked for the watch app target. That's fine except I have complications

**Error1:** Open the application loader like this:

```
Xcode menu --> Xcode --> Open Developer Tool --> Application Loader
```

Open Application Loader using above path, got to preferences (⌘+,) and select only DAV.

[image]

[image]

Comment: i have open this Xcode menu --> Xcode --> Open Developer Tool --> Application Loader its says deliver your app

Comment: i cant see teh Dav thing when i open  Xcode menu --> Xcode --> Open Developer Tool --> Application Loader is just show me "deliver your app"

Comment: Please check my answer that how to open preferences for application loader

Comment: Yes, but uncheck other two